# Import .gLTF animation to THREE.js

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

I used Blender to create a 3D object with simple animation, then I export it as .gLTF file, I tried to import to THREE.js, but I only able to import the 3D object but can't load the animation, how can I load the animation to Three.js?

Answer (score 4):

The most basic code for playing an animation looks like so:

```js
loader.load( 'models.glb', function ( gltf ) {

    var model = gltf.scene;
    var animations = gltf.animations;

    scene.add( model );

    //

    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( model );

    var action = mixer.clipAction( animations[ 0 ] ); // access first animation clip
    action.play();

} );
```

You then have to ensure to update the instance of `AnimationMixer` in your animation loop like so:

```js
var delta = clock.getDelta(); // clock is an instance of THREE.Clock
if ( mixer ) mixer.update( delta );
```

Check out [webgl_animation_skinning_blending](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_blending) to see this code in action.

`three.js R109`